# Deleting a common number from an integer list in swi prolog

Tags: prolog

I use swi-prolog. How can you delete a common number from an integer list? for example, if the list is X=[11,12,13,14,15] and i need to delete 10 from it, so the list will become X=[1,2,3,4,5].
Help required.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
substract(N, L1, L2) :-
    maplist(sub(N), L1, L2).

sub(N, V1, V2) :-
    V2 is V1 - N.
```